# Karate + Gradle : Is there a way to get environment variable value in a .java file and define Postgres DB configuration based on env variable value?

Tags: postgresql, gradle, gitlab-ci, karate

I have a karate framework based application for API testing using Gradle, which stores API response into Postgres DB.
I wanted to make Postgres DB configuration based on environment variable, which is passed through command line,

```
>gradlew test -Dkarate.env=stage
```

As i am a frontend developer, spent lot of time on this but still no luck.
Suggest me a better solution for this, thanks